# Equivalent of \sc to get all uppercase

Tags: small-caps, uppercase

As in the title, by using `\sc` we obtain small caps. Is there an equivalent command to get all uppercase?

I just could not find the answer anywhere.

Comment: Not a switch, only a macro: `\MakeUppercase{text}`

Comment: I see (maybe a bit unfortunate). Out of curiosity, do you know if there is a technical reason behind this?

Comment: uppercasing is not done by simply switching the font (that would make it much easier, but normally such fonts don't exist), it has to parse the argument, expand commands and then exchange the chars. That is quite complicated.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, but let me see if I got what the problem is by proposing something (ugly and clearly an overshot, but still): (1) the difference between small caps and uppercase letters is that every font has a specific – let's call it – subfamily of that fonts that capture small caps, while the same is not true for uppercase letters; (2) when we use \scshape, that calls back *all* the small case letters belonging to the font and this cannot work for uppercase since there is no subfamily; (3) then isn't the problem solved by creating a (redundant) subfamily of uppercase...

Comment: ...letters for every font? Once more, redundant and probably useless, but it should fix the issue, right? (Given that I understood what the original problem is in the first place)

Answer (score 4):

`\sc` is outdated: use `\textsc{}` instead.

To save typing, write your own macro, e.g. `\uc`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

% ~~~ providing some text
\newcommand\txt[0]{Is there an equivalent command to get all uppercase?}

% ~~~ simplifying typing ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\uc[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}

\begin{document}

    Text as is: \txt
    
    Using textsc: {\textsc{\txt}}
    
    Using own macro uc: {\uc\txt}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Note there is a big difference between `\scshape` (to be used instead of `\sc`) and `\textsc`.

Comment: You probably want to write simply `\textsc{\txt}` and `\uc{\txt}`, without external braces.

Comment: Yes and no. The external braces won't hurt, as they just localize the change. Leaving out the inner braces is sloppiness by intention. Both cases shall stimulate the TO to rethink scoping and macros.

Answer (score 3):

There's no “equivalent way”.

The declaration `\scshape` (not `\sc` that's been deprecated for about 30 years) is a font switch, but there's generally no “all caps shape” (even OpenType fonts lack such a feature and I don't really know why).

And “generally” is a gross understatement: I've never seen a font providing an “all caps” shape.

If you want some text to be converted into all caps, pass it as an argument to `\MakeUppercase`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Normal text

\textsc{Caps and Small Caps}

\MakeUppercase{Here I'm shouting!}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I wrote a comment below my original question to see if I got right what the original problem is all about (that I think is related to what you mean when you write "I've never seen a font providing an “all caps” shape." (and I promise I will not you the deprecated command anymore)

Answer (score 2):

As @egreg already told, there is no “equivalent way”. You could only fake it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{relsize}
\newcommand*{\fakeup}{\relscale{1.3}\scshape}

\begin{document}
Normal text

\textsc{Caps and Small Caps}

\MakeUppercase{Here I'm shouting!}

{\fakeup here i'm ugly shouting}!

{\fakeup But here it fails totaly. So there should be 0 points (or even less) for this answer!}

\end{document}
```

But because you need a scalable font, have to take care to use lower case letters only, I would not recommend to do so, nor would it really be useful. And because of this I also do not show the result.